# Detect if the tkinter messagebox is being closed

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

The code bellow makes the problem clear. I found answers on how to achieve the desired behavior with root windows but not with messageboxes. Any input is appreciated!

```
from tkinter import messagebox   
def main():
    while 1:
        if #something:
            messagebox.showinfo("XX", "XX")
        else:
            #active waiting

        #if messagebox is closed : <--- How can this be detected? 
            #do something

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 4):

When you make a message box, the code is paused until you respond to it. In other words, the code is waiting for you to respond so it can continue. Run the following:

```
from tkinter import messagebox   
def main():
    while 1:
        messagebox.showinfo("XX", "XX")
        print("Hello")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

It will make a msgbox and will not print *Hello* until you do some action.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `boolean`. Try this.

```
from tkinter import messagebox

def main():
    while messagebox.showinfo("XX", "XX"):
        print(f"Hello")
         
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```